# A statement implies three other statements, how can I achieve this whilst having the statements in display math mode?

Tags: math-mode

here is what I have at the moment

```
$$\implies\left\{\right.$$ 
  $$5a+5b+16c=-\sum_{i=1}^{i=8}\chi_i(g_1)\chi_i(g_\lambda)$$
  $$a-b=-\sum_{i=1}^{i=8}\chi_i(g_2)\chi_i(g_\lambda)$$
  $$a+b=-\sum_{i=1}^{i=8}\chi_i(g_{2,2})\chi_i(g_\lambda).$$
```

and when the document is built:[image: this is the part of the document containing the above]

What I would really like is to have the implies symbol pointing into the centre of a large left-hand curly bracket which wraps around the three statements, whilst maintaining the statements current formatting e.g. display math mode!

The problem i've been having is whenever I get the statements into an array the summations lose their formatting and turn small & scruffy.

Can anybody help me to achieve this?

Comment: you shouldn't use `$$` in latex but you should never, even in plain use `$$` at the start of a paragraph, or immediately after another display, the spacing will be completely wrong. You should use a mult-line alignment environment such as `align` from `amsmath`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}


zzzz
\begin{gather*}
\sum_{zzz}^{zzz}\ldots\\
\implies\left\{\begin{aligned}
5a+5b+16c&=-\sum_{i=1}^{i=8}\chi_i(g_1)\chi_i(g_\lambda)\\
a-b&=-\sum_{i=1}^{i=8}\chi_i(g_2)\chi_i(g_\lambda)\\
a+b&=-\sum_{i=1}^{i=8}\chi_i(g_{2,2})\chi_i(g_\lambda)\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```